# Debug an Office Add-in in web on Ubuntu platform

Tags: office-addins

I wanted to debug office Add-in on the web in Linux. I installed the package office-addin-debugging and configured.

When I tried to ran the **office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web** command it shows up with some errors. The error comes as follows.

```
office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web
Debugging is being started...
App type: web
Unable to start the dev server. Error: Platform not supported: Linux
Debugging started.
```

I am running the above command in the following environment and its corresponding version.

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Node version: v10.14.0
- Angular CLI: 8.0.0
- Angular: 8.0.0

Apart from this, I tried to validate the manifest file for any errors and removed all the possible errors but no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated !!